# Aptana PHP HTML keeps giving "parsing errors exists"

Tags: php, html, aptana, aptana3

I really enjoy working with Aptana for PHP and HTML. However something that bugs me is that I keep getting "Code formating completed. But parsings errors exists." errors after a while and I am almost certain that my file doesn't have parse errors...

Here is an example that will make Aptana's parser choke:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th><th>Details</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>File Number:</td><td><? echo $FileNumber ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

As soon as one removes the inline php from the table it works again and can parse the file like this:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th><th>Details</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>File Number:</td><td>Inline php removed</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Maybe it's (wrongly) complaining about the missing `;` at the end

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like shortcodes? Try `<?php` instead of `<?`?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I tried it now like: <?php echo $FileNumber; ?> but get an error message stating to look into the log file. The log file has this to say "!ENTRY com.aptana.formatter.epl 4 0 2013-07-10 20:46:45.388
!MESSAGE (Build 3.4.1.201306062137) [ERROR] com.aptana.formatter.epl/debug Error while formatting the code in your editor.
 Please submit a bug report through Studio's support and include the relevant code which triggered this error.
 You may also turn on the com.aptana.formatter.epl/debug at the Studio's Troubleshooting preference page to log more details about this error."

Comment: So definitely looks like a bug :(